# Modal crossing the footer element on mouse enter

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to add an event on mousenter the image should use the modal class and preview the larger image. But it is overlapping with the footer as shown. Can anyone help me with this? I have the code for the same below I am using ajax to load the images and using JSON file which has the image details.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style>
        .gallery {
            list-style-type: none;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
            align-items: center;
            display: block;
        }

        .gallery li {
            float: left;
            padding: 30px;
            position: relative;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        .gray {
            filter: grayscale(100%);
        }

        .modal {
            position: absolute;
            padding: 10px 10px 0 10px;
            background-color: #424242;
            pointer-events: none;
            height: auto;
            width: auto;
        }

        .modal p {
            color: white;
            margin-top: 3px;
            margin-bottom: 3px;
            pointer-events: none;
        }

        .b-footer {
            background-color: #274472;
            color: white;
        }
    </style>
    <title>ABC</title>
    
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "js/data.json",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    $.each(data, function (i, pic) {
                        $("ul.gallery").append("<li><img src='images/square/" + pic.path + "' alt='" + pic.title + "'></li>");
                        $("img").mouseenter(function (event) {
                            $(this).addClass("gray");
                            var title = $(this).attr("alt");
                            var detail;
                            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                                if (data[i].title == title) {
                                    detail = "<div class = 'modal'> <img src='images/medium/" + data[i].path + "' alt='" + data[i].title + "'><p>" + data[i].title + "</p</div>";
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                            $(document.body).append(detail);

                        });

                        $("img").mouseleave(function () {
                            $(this).removeClass("gray");
                            $(".modal").remove();
                        });

                        $("img").mousemove(function (event) {
                            $(this).addClass("gray");
                            $(".modal").css({ top: event.pageY + 10, left: event.pageX + 10, zIndex: 5, display: 'block' });
                        });
                    });
                },
                error: function () {
                    console.log("Picture cannot be loaded");
                }
            });

        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-/bQdsTh/da6pkI1MST/rWKFNjaCP5gBSY4sEBT38Q/9RBh9AH40zEOg7Hlq2THRZ"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <main class="container clearfix">
        <ul class="gallery">
        </ul>
    </main>
    <footer class="text-center p-4 b-footer">
        This is Footer
    </footer>
</body>
```

[image]

Comment: try z-index for footer

Comment: Not working I tried

Answer (score 0):

In the CSS for .modal you have *position:absolute* but you could also put *top:50%* on the next line. Hopefully this places the modal in the vertical middle.